# How do I get the difference between 2 large sets in .net

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, lucene.net

I need to get the set of GUIDs in a remote database which do not exist in an IEnumerable (for context, this is coming from a Lucene index). There are potentially many millions of these Guids.

I currently think that inserting the IEnumerable to the database and doing the difference there will be too expensive (the inserts will hammer the database), but I am prepared to be proven wrong!

Reading both sets into memory is also infeasible due to the amount of data - our existing solution does this and fails with very large sets.

I would like a solution which can operate on a small subset of the data at a time so that we have a constant memory footprint. We have an idea as to how to roll our own implementation of this, but it is non-trivial, so would obviously rather use an existing one if it exists.

If anybody has any recommendations for an existing solution, I'd be grateful to hear them!

Comment: You can use bulk insert on SQL Server. Also, is it infeasible to sort the two datasets separately, and then use a cursor-like system to run through them?

Comment: Will the result be small compared to the size of the remote table and the IEnumerable? In other words will the vast majority of GUIDs be in both sets?

Comment: finnw - The result will normally be small, yes, but there are occasions when the ienumerable is empty and the database contains several million entries. 

Lasse - sorting the database set is trivial, but sorting the ienumerable without loading the entire set into memory less so. We are currently exploring a solution where we merge-sort the ienumerable to a collection which is buffered to disk. Once both collections are sorted we can then perform the difference on small batches at a time on the application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx&ei=K9k2TZO7PMWt8gO5gsDSDA&usg=AFQjCNFPUjfcTJzjAvd8CBLkZgr8V_FVfg&sig2=qGJ2Yqa5USg7r8ZLTnJQjA) to load the guids [very fast](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html) to the database(if it is SQL-Server).